# POSTRGRESQL: pg_dump

Tags: postgresql

Using pg_dump I created a backup database and restored it into a new database. The problem is some columns doesn't have the values displayed. Can I use pg_dump with a where clause to populate the new database with the missing values from the back-up database if the id from the back-up database is find in the new database?

Comment: What you can do is drop the tables that failed (?) to restore, and use `pg_restore`'s options (`-n <schema_name> -t <table_name>`) for restoring those specific tables only.

Comment: The problem is that the same table was populated with data so I will lose the data from the last day if I do what you said.

Comment: you could make a copy of your table, restore it, and then add any missing values from the copy.